# Unable to resolve the error while deploying war file in Grails

Tags: grails

I have generated a war file successfully but while deploying, it gives me error as shown below
can you give me a solution to solve this error.

```
[2011-06-09 10:58:08:468] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
   at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:87)
   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:850)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:724)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1206)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
   at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:723)
   at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:573)
   at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:519)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
   at SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure2.doCall(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:168)
   at SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure2.doCall(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy)
   ... 3 more
```

Comment: Try running `grails clean` and rebuilding the war. If that doesn't work, update with the Grails version and plugin version you're using.

Comment: yes,i did grails clean ,now able to deploy war

Comment: some times after doing grails clean,not able to deploy war

Comment: could you note the versions of Grails you are using as well as the plugin version. I believe there was a breaking change during the 1.3.7 upgrade with an older version of Spring Security Core that could be the problem here. What happens when you do a `grails run-app`?